# How to use dprintf()

Tags: c, pipe

I've been told that the function [dprintf()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dprintf) can be useful in writing data to pipes. Problem is, I can't find any examples that explain how to use it. I've read everything in that link, but still don't quite understand it.

Just a very simple example will help me understand a lot. For instance, if I had a pipe:

```
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
```

and a few pids

```
pid_t ID1, ID2, ID3;
```

how could I use dprintf() to write those pids to the pipe?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`dprintf` works just like `fprintf`, except the first parameter is a file descriptor (i.e. an `int`) instead of a `FILE *`.

```
dprintf(fd[0], "%d : %d : %d", ID1, ID2, ID3);
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you write multiple things in one line like in fprintf?

Comment: @Bob Sure. Everything else besides the first parameter is exactly the same.